# PHP: what method to use when trimming a string to certain amount of chars?

Tags: php, trim

if (strlen($filename) > 70) {
                //trim the string to 70 chars 
                //delete chars from the beginning!
            }

what method do i use.

regards matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the last chars from a string:

```
substr($string, -70);
```

first 70 chars:

```
substr($string, 0, 70);
```

but, of course, you could check [php docs](http://php.net/substr) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

```
$filename = substr($filename, -70);
```